# Div does not proper align with css and back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the site im working on I want users to be scroll and click on icons to "open" them up.For example if a user clicks the about us icon it would have a paragraph of info in which they can scroll up and down the text. Though when I do that I cant figure out 2 things. One how to add a back button when the user clicks on a icon and to open info, (the person click about us icon, icons disappear and text appears, then clicks the back to see the other icons). I tried to have it fade in with the paragraph though that when errors occur.The second issue how can I center the info between the brackets, I tried to use CSS but that doesnt work.

```js
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});


document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  //Secret Code: EADWEARD
  anime({
    targets: "div.right",
    translateX: {
      value: 200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
    targets: "div.left",
    translateX: {
  value: -200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });

  if (e.keyCode == "40") {
//this is down
//this will open it up
slot.prev();

  } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    slot.next();
  }
}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
  anime({
targets: "div.right",
translateX: {
  value: 200,
  duration: 500
}
  });
  anime({
    targets: "div.left",
translateX: {
  value: -200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });
  var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
  if (delta < 0) {
    //This is for the scrolling down
    // animation opens up the brakets

    slot.prev();

  }
  if (delta > 0) {
slot.next();
  }
});


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function(){
  if($(this).index() == '1'){
console.log("the fucks");

$('#aboutID').fadeOut("slow", function(){
var div = $("<p id='foo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing         elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                                                                         </p> ").hide();
var but = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
$('#theMiddle').replaceWith(div);
$('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
$('#secondbutton').fadeIn("slow");
});



  }if($(this).index() == '2'){
console.log("jobs page");
  }
});
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 390px;
}

div.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}

div.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 870px;
}

#left,#right{
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#middle{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
#theMiddle{
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}
#foo {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>Underscores</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-    
    slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css">
  </style>
  <script     
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js">
  </script>
  <script     
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>


</head>

<body>


  <div id="left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png"     
alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="middle" id="theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt=""     

class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" 
    class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" 
    alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="right"><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Please add a snippet

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena snippet of? the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, I think this is what you are trying to do, check the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zLbysexg/6/

The only change required is in the CSS for #foo id for getting the paragraph in the center, where the icon was:

```
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

Also, I couldn't find anything related to a back button in your code.

Comment: for the back button thats in the JS file like 80 ish.     $('#secondbutton').fadeIn("slow");
Im lost on how i can integrate it

Comment: @joshau Here, check this https://jsfiddle.net/zLbysexg/14/
You create the button: `var but = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");`
Then you must add it to the HTML DOM, you can use `append()` or `prepend()` functions to do so, to show you, I have appended the button to the main `body` tag.

Hope this solves your problem.